# UVM ports: put,get,export, analysis

Tags: port, uvm

I am trying to master in UVM, and completely lost in UVM ports. Please help better understand the ports.

So as I understood there are 3 main types of ports

1. Put-> get    : producer put data and consumer gets the data. This is blocking statement.
2. Put-> Export->Imp
3. Analysis->Subscriber : producer transmit the data and other subscribers gets it. This is non-blocking statement.

Also there are TLM_FIFOs  which allows to buffer the transaction for later usage. It has 2 types:  `uvm_tlm_fifo` and `uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo`.

And my questions are:

1. Is my understanding right?
2. What is the difference between get and export?
3. What is the difference between `uvm_tlm_fifo` and `uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo`?

Thanks
Hayk

Answer (score 1):

The use of TLM interfaces isolates each component from changes in
other components throughout the environment.

For ports understanding, there are two common terminologies: **Producer** and **Consumer**. Instead of producer and consumer, think in terms of **initiator** and **target** of communication between components.

> An **initiator** is always having a **port** connected to it. Just like driver has seq_item_**port**.
>
> A **target** always have an **export**. Just like sequencer havng seq_item_**export**.

For Put/Get ports:

```
Initiator/Producer:
port.put(tr);

Target/Consumer: (Note the Input in task)
task pet(input simple_trans t);
//...
endtask
```

In **put** port, **initiator** is the **producer** which *puts* a **transaction** for the **consumer**. **Initiator/Producer blocks** till the put task is unblocked by Target/Consumer.

```
Initiator/Consumer:
port.get(tr);

Target/Producer:(Note the Output in task)
task get(output simple_trans t);
//...
endtask
```

While in get port, the initiator is the consumer. A **consumer** requests/asks for transaction and producer provides it. **Initiator/Consumer** blocks till the get task is unblocked by Target/Producer.

The put/get ports are typically used to have **operational** behavior of a system. These ports are used for **one-to-one communication**.

**Analysis ports** are generally used to **broadcast** the transaction. The **write** method is always **non blocking**. There may be **zero or more connections** to analysis ports. Again the rules for initiator and target remains the same.

```
Initiator:
port.write(tr);

Target:(Note the function, not task)
function void write(simple_trans tr);
//...
endfunction
```

All the ports requires implementation of methods in user's classes. The `uvm_*_imp` is used for the same. While **buffering** of data can be done through **FIFO**s.

For analysis ports, `uvm_analysis_fifo` is used, since these FIFO must have the ability to **further broadcast** the transaction. The default size of analysis FIFO is **unbounded**.

While `uvm_tlm_fifo` is used when put/get ports are used, that is, for one-to-one communication. The default size of analysis FIFO is **1**, which can be changed to **unbounded**.

Again, FIFOs always puts/gets the data **upon request** from a component, henceforth there is an **export** type of connection at both the ends.

For further information, refer to [UVM User Guide](http://accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/uvm/uvm_users_guide_1.1.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much sharvil111 for detail explanation!!   
So can we say that export and get is the same?  
  
Also if put-get is used for one-to-one communication, than why we need uvm_tlm_fifo there? In other words, **Initiator/Producer** blocks when sending the transaction and waits until **Target/Consumer** consume that transaction, why there is a need to have **FIFO** there?

Comment: Port/Export are the types of **connections**. While put/get are types of **port**. The terms initiator - producer, target - consumer refer to the components, both are different terms. FIFOs are used to **buffer** the data. That is, for temporary storage. Lets say your monitor has sent some data to subscriber and subscriber is busy processing some other transaction, then that data is kept in FIFO to process later on, thereby FIFOs are useful.

Comment: sharvil111 thank you very much for explanation. 
I think I need to read more about ports and connections, if you can point me some docs that would be great!

Comment: @haykp - Chapter 2 from UVM User guide link in my answer is a good material for ports. Moreover [this](http://www.testbench.in/UT_13_UVM_TLM_1.html) site may be helpful for understanding the basics.